# '_csv.writer' object is not iterable. how to append to a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

start of the code and if the user choses y works fine just if the user choses n

```
import time
import csv

def login():
    print("Welcome...")
    welcome = raw_input("Do you have an acount? y/n")
    if welcome == "y":
        with open("user.csv",'r') as file:
            username=raw_input("Enter username")
            password=raw_input("Enter password")
            fileReader=csv.reader(file)
            for row in fileReader:
                if username==row[0] and password==row[1]:
                    print("access granted")
                    return username
                else:
                    print("denied")
                    login()


    elif welcome == "n":
        with open("user.csv",'a') as file:
            username=raw_input("Enter username")
            password=raw_input("Enter password")
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for row in csv_writer:
                username==row[0] and password==row[1]

    else:
        print("denied")
        login()
```

csv file:
miles,miesgw
bob,phone
simon,smells

problem occurs when users input is n
unsure in how to append to the csv file and save.

Comment: Isn't "csv_writer" in your case is for uppending the row, where you trying to iterate over it (read lines instead)?

Comment: im not sure as don't think 'csv_writer' is the correct code

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
with open("user.csv",'a') as file:
    username=raw_input("Enter username")
    password=raw_input("Enter password")
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
    csv_writer.writerow([username, password])
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'csvfile' is not defined

Comment: sorry that was a typo. it should be `file`. updated the answer

Comment: when I create an account it is then not saving the next time I try to enter it in a new run of the code

Comment: are you opening that file with `'w'` anywhere else in the code? if so then it will get overwritten

Comment: I tested it again the code snippet works for multiple calls. Can't say why it isn't working for you without seeing the rest of the code.